# Creation of git repository based on ADMIN approval

Tags: github

I want to use git hub API like octokit.rest.repos.createUsingTemplate to create a repository. But instead of creating repo directly, I want a request to be raised to ADMIN. Once ADMIN approve the request, then only the repository will be created. Is there a way to do it?

I used octokit.rest.repos.createUsingTemplate directly. But instead I want repo creation should go via an approval process.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that and prevent repos from being created through normal means.

What you could do is look into GitOps for these kinds of things. GitOps is a method where you use git (or GitHub) events to t
trigger processes.

You could for example let users create an issue in a repo requesting the new repo, and have an admin approve that request by labeling the issue (something only someone with triage or up rights can do).

Keep in mind that this will not directly disallow repos from being created the normal way.

There is a setting at the org level to prevent users from creating repos though, so together this could give the intended result.